# Acesso negado. (code: 5) PHP

Tags: php, diretório

Estou usando o código abaixo para tentar ler os arquivos em um diretório.

```
$dir = "\\\\192.168.44.19\Controles\Inventario de Equipamentos\A\ " ;
$pasta= opendir($dir);


echo("<li data-role='list-divider'><a href='#'>B</a></li>"); 

while ($arquivo = readdir($pasta)){
  if ($arquivo != '.' && $arquivo != '..'){
     echo "<li><a href='".$dir.$arquivo."' rel='external' >".$arquivo."</a></li>";
  }
}
```

Porém recebo a mensagem de **erro**:

> Acesso negado. (code: 5) in C:\wamp\www\termos\index.php on line 30

Comment: Manualmente, pelo Meu Computador ou acessando com o Terminal do Linux o endereço `192.168.44.19\Controles\Inventario de Equipamentos\A\` você consegue acessar tranquilamente?

Comment: você precisa mudar a permissão da pasta para leitura, se você estiver usando linux faça `sudo chmod -R 777 "nome da pasta"`

Comment: @RafaelAcioly chmod 777 é um bocado perigoso. ele só precisa de acesso de leitura.

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian, sim. Acesso normalmente.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, o meu usuário está com Controle Total na pasta

Comment: @MoshMage, é apenas pra uso interno. Não sei se teria muito problema

Comment: Faça um `is_dir($dir)`, verifica se o retorno é `true`.

Comment: @DeeSouza false

Comment: Significa que não existe. Tem certeza de que esse é o caminho ?

Comment: @DeeSouza, conferir o caminho. Realmente estava incorreto. Corrigi, mas mesmo assim o erro permanece.

Comment: Essas quatro barras no começo são normais ? Eu nunca vi isso. Seria bom você renomear as pastas e deixá-las sem espaços.

Comment: @DeeSouza com ou sem as 4 barras, mesmo erro. As pastas infelizmente não tenho como renomear ...

Comment: Tenta acessar pelo nome da máquina ao invés do seu IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução encontrada

É necessário configurar o serviço com algum usuário de rede que tenha a permissão de acesso ao diretório.
Fui em Iniciar>Executar>services.msc e achei o serviço wampapache. 
Depois cliquei com o botão direito>propriedades>logon e coloquei os dados da conta com acesso.

Resolvido

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, este problema pode estar ligado a vários fatores, internos da linguagem ou até externos a ela, como por exemplo: Firewall, Rede, Permissões de Pastas e Usuários.

### Firewall

O computador que esta sendo acessado esta com firewall ou ant-vírus que não esteja deixando o hospedeiro entrar.

### Rede

Rede esta com permissões corretamente no compartilhamento de pastas, grupo de rede e etc?

### Permissões de pasta

Permissões de pastas estão corretas e compartilhas corretamente na rede? permissões para usuários específicos ou grupo?

No windows é pouco fraco o gerenciamento de permissões, fora Windows Server que é maior o controle. Da uma olhada nisso.

Caso a máquina que esteja acessando seja terminal UNIX será preciso definir permissões de leitura para a pasta:

`chmod 0755 /path/folder/ -R`

Bom, não é um erro de código aparentemente, e sim de permissões de hospedeiro. De uma olhada nessas dicas e me diz o que achou.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. O Firewall e antivirus estão desativados. EM relação a rede, o meu usuário está com acesso full. Em relação ao servidor, estou usando uma virtual box dentro de um Windows Server.

Comment: Através do browser tem acesso normalmente do compartilhamento?